# How to change toggle text on show hide using javascript

Tags: javascript

Example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showme(id) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        if (divid.style.display == 'block') divid.style.display = 'none';
        else divid.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

<a onclick="showme('widget');" href="#">Show Widget</a>

<div id="widget" style="display:none;">
This is a widget
</div>
```

I want change text `Show Widget` & `Hide Widget`. Let me know

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/SLcDE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showme(id, linkid) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        var toggleLink = document.getElementById(linkid);
        if (divid.style.display == 'block') {
            toggleLink.innerHTML = 'Show Widget';
            divid.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            toggleLink.innerHTML = 'Hide Widget';
            divid.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>

<a id="toggler" onclick="showme('widget', this.id);" href="#">Show Widget</a>

<div id="widget" style="display:none;">
This is a widget
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest: `onclick="return showme(...)` and return false in showme.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text in your toggle block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showme(id) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        if (divid.style.display == 'block') {
          divid.style.display = 'none';
          $('#toggleDisplay').text('Show Widget');
        }
        else{ 
          divid.style.display = 'block';
          $('#toggleDisplay').text('Hide Widget');
        }
    }
</script>

<a onclick="showme('widget');" href="#" id="toggleDisplay" >Show Widget</a>

<div id="widget" style="display:none;">
This is a widget
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<script type="text/javascript">`<br/>
    `function showme(id) {`<br/>
        `var divid = document.getElementById(id);`<br/>
        `var clicky = document.getElementById("clicky");`<br/>
        `if (divid.style.display == 'block') {divid.style.display = 'none';clicky.innerHTML = "Show Widget";}`<br/>
        `else {divid.style.display = 'block'; clicky.innerHTML = "Hide Widget";}
    }`<br/>
`</script>`<br/>

`<a onclick="showme('widget');" href="#" id="clicky">Show Widget</a>`<br/>

`<div id="widget" style="display:none;">`<br/>
`This is a widget`<br/>
`</div>`<br/>
```