# Query or php issue? My code for jquery showme toggle isn't working (code mentioned in previous post)

Tags: jquery, toggle

I was so excited to read the post about using toggle to click and show and click and hide text ([How to change toggle text on show hide using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672984/how-to-change-toggle-text-on-show-hide-using-javascript/4673081#4673081)), but then I couldn't get the code to work. When  I click on the underlined hyperlink no text shows up.

```
In function.php:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script('SHOWME',get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/wp-     
includes/js/jquery/SHOWME.js');
}



In ftp drive:
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
$(function showme(id)) {
    var divid = $(document.getElementById(id));
    $(if (divid.style.display == 'block') divid.style.display = 'none');
    $(else divid.style.display = 'block');
   }
    array('jquery')
);
   }
  });



  HTML in page:

  <a onclick="SHOWME('list');" href="#"><h3>Air Barrier Association of America (ABAA)     
  Certification Training</h3>
  </a>
  <div class="showMe" style="display: none;">This is a widget</div>
  <div class="showMe" style="display: none;">This is a widget</div>
  <div class="showMe" style="display: none;">Self Adhered &amp; Fluid Applied Installer         
  Training</div>
```

Comment: You should read up on jQuery. $(document.getElementById(id)) = $("#"+id). jQuery also handles hiding and showing elements, no need for using "display" directly.

Answer (score 0):

The script doesn't work because you have syntax errors in it.

You have misunderstood how to use jQuery. It's a library that you use from regular Javascript code, you don't use it by putting `$(...)` around every line in the Javascript code.

Let's take it step by step. Stripping of the code that is wrong would give you:

```
function showme(id) {
  var divid = document.getElementById(id);
  if (divid.style.display == 'block') {
    divid.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    divid.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Using jQuery in the code to accomplish the same would look like this:

```
function showme(id) {
  var divid = $('#' + id);
  if (divid.is(':visible')) {
    divid.hide();
  } else {
    divid.show();
  }
}
```

You can also use the `toggle` method to do the same:

```
function showme(id) {
  $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

Of course you have to call `showme` in the HTML code, not `SHOWME`, as Javascript is case sensetive, and you have to add the id `list` to the element that you want to toggle.

---

If you intended to toggle the elements with the class `showMe`, that would be:

```
function showme(className) {
  $('.' + className).toggle();
}
```

and you call it with `showme('showMe')` instead of `showme('list')`.

---

You can also bind the event in the Javascript code instead of having the inline `onclick` attribute. You use the `ready` event for this, so that the event is bound after the page is ready, so that the link exists:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    showme('list');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes. I'm still getting the hang of jquery. Thank you.

Comment: If I use the code directly above this comment box, do I use the following html?

Comment: <a href="showme"><h3>Air Barrier Association of America (ABAA) Certification Training</h3></a>

Comment: If I use the code above this comment box, how do I tag the html?Shouldn't "list" have a hash tag before it?
<a href="showme"><h3>Air Barrier Association of America (ABAA) Certification Training</h3></a> 
<div id="list"><ul>
 <li>Self-Adhered &amp; Fluid Applied Installer Training</li>
 <li>Spray Polyurethane Installer Certification Training</li>
 <li>Quality Assurance Program Administrator</li>
</ul></div>

Comment: By the way, thank you for taking the time to explain JQuery in such detail. This was really helpful information.

Comment: When specifying an id in HTML, there is no hash character, e.g. `id="list"`. When you target the element in a jQUery selector you use CSS-like syntax, so the hash character specifies that it's an id, e.g. `$('#list')`.

Comment: Sorry. That is what I did. When I click on the link enabled ABAA, the text below it remains hidden. In CSS I applied the following #list {display:none;}

Comment: what else might I be missing?

Comment: @Salsamama: You have a `href="showme"` in the link, which will make the browser try to go to a page named `showme`. Using `href="#"` will just make the browser jump to the top of the page, but best is of course to use `preventDefault` in the event handler, e.g. `$('a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); showme('list'); });`.

Comment: @Salsamama: Use `<a href="#">` if you don't need an actual URL to link to, it will do minimal damage if it's used anyway for some reason. The anchor element still needs a `href` attribute to be a link, otherwise it becomes a bookmark.

Comment: I wrapped div tags with the id="list" around a ul of three lines as shown below but the text still won't appear.

Comment: <div id="list" style="display:none;">
 <ul>
          <li>Self-Adhered &amp; Fluid Applied Installer Training</li>
   <li>Spray Polyurethane Installer Certification Training</li>
          <li>Quality Assurance Program Administrator</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: I had this problem before. It executes in js bins and fiddle but not on my web page. What would cause a problem like that if the code is right and placed in the right locations?

Comment: I have my js file in ftp and it is referenced in the functions.php file as so:add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_scripts_method");
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script("showme",get_template_directory_uri() . "/admin/wp-     
includes/js/jquery/showme.js")};

Comment: @Salsamama: I can't see the page, it's password protected.

Comment: @Salsamama: You have two elements with the id `list` in the page. An id should be unique in the page, otherwise it won't work properly.

Comment: On click, the page pops up to the browser. Is there another element I can use besides #?

Comment: @Salsamama: Use `e.preventDefault();` in the click handler (and accept the parameter `e`). That will keep the link from being activated.

Comment: It is still not showing the  div "list" on click.  I unplugged all the plugins. What else might interfer with a jQuery script?

Comment: @Salsamama: Do you have any code that actually binds the click event on that link? When I try the code, the only event bound on it is the one that is bound on all links in the page.

Comment: just the div id="list" which references the js file in functions.php

Comment: Is this the event that is bound to all the links on the page<a href="#">show/hide </a>

Comment: $(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#list').toggle();
    });
});

Comment: Do you run that code before the code that sets the `onclick` property on all links? In that case it will replace the first event handler. If you use only jQuery code to bind events, you can have multiple events, but if you set the `onclick` property on elements you can only have one handler for the event.

Comment: the code lives in my ftp site and then, i reference it in the functions.php file. Should I put the code before the header code in functions.php?Right now, I've only attached "list" a href="#" to one element, the first list which isn't showing, so it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: all the content is showing on the page now it was because I had <a href="#<>">Title</a> immediately after the word: ASHRAE 62.2

Comment: the problem of being able to show hidden content remains...Any other thoughts? Thank you again for your patience. I'm new to trouble shooting jquery issues.

Comment: I can't find that code at all in the page. I haven't looked through all the scripts that are included, but it all looks like ready-made libraries.

Comment: Are you looking at the scripts mentioned on the page? Yes. I believe that they are all from ready-made libraries. Are you saying that I should look for jquery codes in firebug on my page which that don't come from the jquery library?

Comment: @Salsamama: I'm saying that I can't find the script `$(function(){ $('a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $('#list').toggle(); }); });` anywhere in the page.